# Prove that a strongly convex function imples $2c(F(w)-F_*) \leq ||\nabla F(w)||_2^2$

Tags: convex-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

The proof is given as follows:

[image]

***My question is why is the unique minimizer $\bar{w}_* = w - \frac{1}{c} \nabla F(w)$?***

Comment: Are you asking why is it unique or why the minimiser takes the given expression? If it's the latter, then you need to compute the derivative and set it to zero.

Comment: @CheeHan why it takes the given expression? That is the solution for all strongly convex functions?

Answer (score 2):

Given
\begin{align*} 
q(\bar w) & = F(w) + \nabla F(w)^T(\bar w - w) + \frac{c}{2}\|\bar w - w\|_2^2 \\
& = F(w) + \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{\partial F}{\partial w_j}\left(\bar w_j - w_j\right) + \frac{c}{2}\sum_{j=1}^d \left(\bar w_j - w_j\right)^2, 
\end{align*}
its partial derivative with respect to $\bar w_j$ for any $j=1,\dots, d$ is 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial q(\bar w)}{\partial\bar w_j} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial w_j} + \frac{c}{2}\Big(2\left(\bar w_j - w_j\right)\Big) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial w_j} + c\left(\bar w_j - w_j\right). 
\end{align*}
Consequently, the gradient of $q(\bar w)$ is 
$$ \nabla q(\bar w) = \nabla F(w) + c(\bar w - w). $$
The critical point of $q(\bar w)$ is found by setting $\nabla q(\bar w) = 0$ and solving for $\bar w$:
\begin{align*}
\nabla F(w) + c\left(\bar w - w\right) & = 0 \\
c\left(\bar w - w\right) & = - \nabla F(w) \\
\bar w - w & = -\frac{1}{c}\nabla F(w) \\
\bar w & = w - \frac{1}{c}\nabla F(w) =\colon \bar w^*
\end{align*}
as desired. Note that this argument doesn't prove that $\bar w^*$ is the minimiser or maximiser.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier argument for quadratic functionals: completing the square. The following identity is just as easy to prove as the 1D version you know from highschool:
$$ \alpha ‖x‖^2 + \beta · x = \alpha\left\|x+\frac1{2\alpha}{\beta} \right\|^2 -  \frac{‖\beta‖^2}{4\alpha}$$
In your case, this yields (remember, $w$ is fixed, $\bar w$ is varying) with $$x = w - \bar w, \quad \alpha = \frac{c}{2},\quad  \beta = \nabla F(w)$$
$$⟹ q(\bar w) = C(w) + \frac c{2}\left\|\bar w - \left(w-\frac1c∇ F(w)\right)\right\|^2 $$
where $C(w) = F(w)-\frac{‖∇ F(w)‖^2}{2c}$. Its now obvious what the minimiser and minimum is.